# Get Directions details from Directions Widget

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, widget

I have created a Directions Widget as below

```
 var directionsW = new Directions({
            map: map,
            routeTaskUrl: 
            "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/arcgis/rest/services/CALCUL_ITINERAIRE/NAServer/Route"
           
        }, "dir");

  directionsW.startup();
```

Could you please confirm if can I get the route directions details, if yes could you please let me know how ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the route directions from the [Directions widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Directions.html). One way is to [watch](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-core-watchUtils.html#watch) for changes to the [`lastRoute`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Directions-DirectionsViewModel.html#lastRoute) property on the viewModel.

```
  view.when(() => {
    directionsWidget.when(() => {
      watchUtils.watch(directionsWidget.viewModel, "lastRoute", () => {
        if (directionsWidget.viewModel.lastRoute) {
          console.log(
            "routeName:",
            directionsWidget.viewModel.lastRoute.routeResults[0].routeName
          );
          console.log(
            "totalDriveTime:",
            directionsWidget.viewModel.lastRoute.routeResults[0]
            .directions.totalDriveTime
          );
          console.log(
            "totalLength:",
            directionsWidget.viewModel.lastRoute.routeResults[0]
            .directions.totalLength
          );
        }
      });
    });
  });
```